# Keep Twilio clientDevice in memory on Android so call can be placed immediately

Tags: android, android-service, twilio, background-service, android-application-class

I am developing an app that is designed to allow emergency calls using Twilio - my code is derived from https://github.com/twilio/twilio-client-quickstart-android.

All I've done which is different to the GitHub code is create a separate `AlertManager` class that does the Twilio initialisation outside of an `Activity`.

At any moment a user must be able to open the app and tap a button which will (as quickly as possible) make an emergency call using Twilio.

My issue is that Twilio requires the creation of a `clientDevice` by requesting a "capabilityToken" from my server. That is fine, but the token expires after an hour.

Assuming there is always an external internet connection, how can I make it so my application always has a `clientDevice` (with a valid token) object available in memory somewhere, such that when the user enters the `Activity` to make an emergency call, they are able to do it immediately without the app having to request a new token nor create a new `clientDevice`?

From a quick test using Airplane mode and hard coding a valid token it appears the Twilio SDK can create a `clientDevice` as long as it has a token, i.e. only one network request is required to retrieve the token, rather than two if another is required to create the `clientDevice`.

I know I could use some kind of `Service` to fetch tokens, but I'm not entirely sure where I can store my `clientDevice`. It can't reside inside an `Activity` since the app will not always be running. I did wonder about creating my own `Application` class but as I understand it Android can and will create new instances of that class when it needs to which would then result in my `clientDevice` being removed from memory. Or is it possible to store it in the `Service` and then send some kind of broadcast to the Service to make the call?

I hope that makes some kind of sense and if anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I have a couple of ideas about the token expiry.

First up, you can set the token expiry time up to 24 hours.

Second, you could use [Twilio's `AccessManager` library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/access-token-lifecycle) that takes an access token and lets you listen to events for when a token is close to expiry or when it expires.

I don't know about keeping live objects while your application is in the background though I'm afraid. Hopefully someone else can help you here.